# AWS RDS Aurora (MySQL) Replication design

Tags: amazon-web-services, replication, rds

I hope someone can help clarify the replication of AWS RDS Aurora for me, it states "It has fault-tolerant and self-healing storage built for the cloud that replicates six copies of your data across three Availability Zones"

so how does it handle regions with only 2 - AZ? For example, Canada?

In case it picks other region to achieve this then what option do I have to enforce data residency so that my data is not replicated out side of my region and I accept the risk etc.

Thanks.

Comment: It's a good question. I strongly suspect it'll just use the two zones - cross-region replication would probably slow things down too much for the use case. Ultimately, I think you'll only get a solid answer to this by asking AWS Support.

Comment: Thanks. ceejayoz. I'll fill a quick query to AWS support and circle back on what I learned.

Answer (score 2):

just wanted to share that I got the confirmation from AWS. "internal AWS services like Aurora are still able to maintain six copies of the database volume across three different Availability Zones, through an internal AZ. AWS uses that AZ for internal purpose and that AZ is not available to public. Therefore your data will only reside in one region instead of multiple regions.'